# Getting constant accuracies for training and validation sets despite their losses are changing during CNN training?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, keras, tensorflow, convolutional-neural-network

As the title clearly describes the issue I've been experiencing during the training of my CNN model, the accuracies of training and validation sets are constant despite the losses of them are changing. I have included the detail regarding the model and its training setup below. What may cause this issue?

Here is the data that was used by training (`X_train` & `y_train`), validation, and test sets (`X_test` and `y_test`):

```
df = pd.read_csv(CSV_PATH, sep=',', header=None)
print(f'Shape of all data: {df.shape}')
    
y = df.iloc[:, -1].values
X = df.iloc[:, :-1].values

encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(y)
encoded_Y = encoder.transform(y)
dummy_y = to_categorical(encoded_Y)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, dummy_y, test_size=0.3, random_state=RANDOM_STATE)

X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1))
X_test = X_test.reshape((X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1))
```

Here are the shapes of training and test sets:

```
Shape of X_train: (1322, 10800, 1)
Shape of Y_train: (1322, 3)
Shape of X_test: (567, 10800, 1)
Shape of y_test: (567, 3)
```

Here is my CNN model:

```
# Model hyper-parameters
activation_fn = 'relu'
n_lr = 1e-4
weight_decay = 1e-4
batch_size = 64
num_epochs = 200*10*10
num_classes = 3
n_dropout = 0.6
n_momentum = 0.5
n_kernel = 5
n_reg = 1e-5

# the sequential model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(128, n_kernel, input_shape=(10800, 1)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation(activation_fn))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=2))

model.add(Dropout(n_dropout))

model.add(Conv1D(256, n_kernel))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation(activation_fn))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=2))

model.add(Dropout(n_dropout))

model.add(GlobalAveragePooling1D()) # have tried model.add(Flatten()) as well

model.add(Dense(256, activation=activation_fn))
model.add(Dropout(n_dropout))
model.add(Dense(64, activation=activation_fn))
model.add(Dropout(n_dropout))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

adam = Adam(lr=n_lr, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=weight_decay)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=adam, metrics=['acc'])
```

Here is how I have evaluated the model:

```
Y_pred = model.predict(X_test, verbose=0)
y_pred = np.argmax(Y_pred, axis=1)
y_test_int = np.argmax(y_test, axis=1)
```

And, my model always predicts the same class of three classes during the model evaluation as you can see from the classification result below (via `classification_result(y_test_int, y_pred)` function):

```
          precision    recall  f1-score   support

  normal      0.743     1.000     0.852       421
     apb      0.000     0.000     0.000        45
     pvc      0.000     0.000     0.000       101
```

The model was trained using the `EarlyStopping` callback of `Keras`. So, the training has continued for `4,173` epochs. Here is the obtained losses during the training for training and validation sets:

[image: loss]

Here is the obtained accuracies during the training for training and validation sets:

[image: accuracy]

The model was implemented using `Keras`, and hosted on `Google Colab`. Please feel free to ask any further information regarding my model.

Comment: There could be a number of reasons why your model isn't improving. In the 1st `Conv1D` layer, the input shape is `( 10800 , 1 )`. If you're trying to classify such a long sequence, I'd insist you add more `Conv1D` layers. Probably your model doesn't have that many parameters to approximate the input vs. output relation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @ShubhamPanchal. To be honest, I've already increased the number of `Conv1D` layers but the result was the same as I oddly got constant accuracy values for training and validation sets despite the changes in the loss values.

Comment: You can try decaying the learning rate after a specific number of steps/epochs. So, as the loss function approaches the global minima, the learning rate is reduced according to a given scheme ( as discussed [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/learning-rate-schedules-and-adaptive-learning-rate-methods-for-deep-learning-2c8f433990d1) ) and it will avoid skipping the minima.

Comment: I've employed the `ReduceLROnPlateau` callback as follows but nothing is changed: `ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1, patience=2, min_lr=0.000001, verbose=1)`. Also, tried `LearningRateScheduler` as well. It did not change the issue, too. Is there anything you can recommend me to try?